# Laravel 5 Not Finding Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm brand new to Laravel and am having trouble loading my models in order to seed the database. I have tried both the Laravel 4 method of composer.json and the Laravel 5 PSR-4.

#### DatabaseSeeder.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\Client::truncate();
        \App\Models\Module::truncate();
        \App\Models\ModuleConnection::truncate();

        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('ClientsTableSeeder');
        $this->call('ModulesTableSeeder');
        $this->call('ConncetionsTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

#### Client.php

These are in app\Models at the moment, but I have tried them in app next to Users.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Client extends \Eloquent {
    proteced $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

#### Module.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Module extends \Eloquent {
    proteced $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

#### ModuleConnection.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class ModuleConnection extends \Eloquent {
    proteced $fillable = ['id', 'clientid', 'moduleid', 'apiconn', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

#### The error

This is when I run php artisan db:seed

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Class 'App\Models\Client' not found
```

I'm sure it's something stupid I'm missing as a beginner! Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that your model folder name have a capital `Models` in the front. Also you forgot to put this code after define namespace. `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` You must extends `Model` not `Eloquent` except you specify like this. `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent`. Then run this command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Faiz. The folder name is capitalized, yes. I edited the code as you suggested in my post - still the same error. Might have mistaken the last superclass part though.

Comment: Have you renamed your app? Have you ever run the command `php artisan app:name`? If so, you will need to use that name instead of 'App'

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably have to extend Eloquent and not \Eloquent. When you add a \ on your usage, you are telling PHP to find an Eloquent in its root namespace. So:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Module extends Eloquent {
    proteced $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Second, there's no need to do a `composer dumpautoload` because your App namespace was included by your Laravel instalation:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

This is telling the autoloader to search for your namespaced classes in the `app/` path.

The thing you have to check is if the file Client.php is in the folder:

```
app/Models/Client.php
```

And named as is. Other than that I don't see a problem in your code.